# How to copy data from SSAS (on-premise) to Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure-analysis-services

My company plans to copy all data from on-premise SQL Services Analysis Services (2017 tabular) to Azure Analysis Services on a periodic basis.  We want to do this at least once a day, and then use the Azure Analysis Services version for Power BI reporting only.  The idea is to reduce load on the on-premise cube, and to improve response in Power BI.

1. Is this a recommended design for reporting?
2. What are the methods available for the periodic copy of data (and pros and cons for each)?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nandan’s approach, you could continue to refresh the model on premises, then backup and restore to Azure Analysis Services. I shared a PowerShell script which [automates](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/README.md#backuprestore) this operation.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell us what is the data source for the on prem SSAS cube ?

In case it a SQL server, rather than syncing data from SSAS to AAS, you can directly refresh the AAS with on prem SQL server as the source via on prem gateway.

And in case if the cube is only used for reporting(powerbi), then having AAS is enough rather than maintaining SSAS and AAS.

Comment: I am new to the company, but was told that there are many inputs to the on-premise cube that cannot send data to the cloud, as well as outputs from the on-premise cube to systems that cannot receive data from the cloud.  The idea was to first create a copy of the cube in the cloud for reporting (to reduce load on-premise and increase report performance) and later upgrade other systems and eventually remove the on-premise cube.  The method envisioned by the team is SSIS to move data from SSAS to AAS.

Comment: Hey,
Can you please provide the list of input sources currently in SSAS ?
And also , what is the current compatibility of the SSAS model? That might define some additional efforts